# solution of Coupled second-order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I desperately need to solve a coupled system of linear second order differential equations of the form:

$ a_1x''+ b_1x' + c_1y'' + d_1y' =0 $

$ a_2x'' + b_2x' + c_2y'' + d_2y' + e_2y = 0 $

initial conditions are :

$ y(0)=y_0,  y'(0)=x(0)=x'(0)=0.  $

x and y are displacement in time.

What method do you suggest for solving this system? Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Try writing it in matrix form and computing the matrix exponential.

Comment: @Moo to explain more detail the system I should say that the system is a motion equation for coupled (sway and roll; in hydrodynamic), there are solutions for diagonal mass matrix when M12=M21=0, but in my case all paramaters of mass matrix are non-zero value (m11, m12, m21 and m22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of linear ODE with constant coefficients, it is known that the general solution is a linear combination of exponential functions on the form $k\,e^{r\,t}$ where the various values of $r$ , real or complex, are the roots of a polynomial equation. So, a method to solve the system is to presume of the form of particular solutions and determine the parameters of them, as done below :

[image]